# Get time as fixed size integer

Tags: c++, time

When you get time
via this structure: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/
one can see the values (e.g., `tm_sec, tm_min`) are all `int`.
Problem is I wanted to stores these `int`s somewhere.
But I wanted to use `int32_t` type instead of `int`, so that the size is fixed.
Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ gets the `struct tm` type from C. According to the C standard, these elements of `struct tm` have certain ranges:

> #### C99 §7.23.1 Components of time
>
> The `tm` structure shall contain at least the following members, in any order. The semantics of the members and their normal ranges are expressed in the comments.
>
> ```
> int tm_sec;   //seconds after the minute — [0, 60]
> int tm_min;   //minutes after the hour — [0, 59]
> int tm_hour;  //hours since midnight — [0, 23]
> int tm_mday;  //day of the month — [1, 31]
> int tm_mon;   //months since January — [0, 11]
> int tm_year;  //years since 1900
> int tm_wday;  //days since Sunday — [0, 6]
> int tm_yday;  //days since January 1 — [0, 365]
> int tm_isdst; // Daylight Saving Time flag
> ```

These values can be safely cast to `int32_t`.

Comment: I do not believe `time_t` is guaranteed to have the same structure on every implementation and hence is safe to store "as-is". From memory the standard only says that "`time_t` is an arithmetic type which can represent time". So it will represent every possible time, but it may not be a suitable type for storage.

Comment: @Thomas I misunderstood the question earlier, I've modified it.

Comment: So using like `int32_t t = (int32_t) tmStruct.tm_sec;` is fine and `t` will have size 4 bytes?

Comment: @Yu Hao: Thanks but on some platforms int maybe 6 or 8 (I am not sure) bytes right? how would this work correctly then?

Comment: @dmcr_code Because they have limited range. e.g, for an `int` within [0, 365], it's always OK to convert it to `int32_t` no matter how many bytes `int` holds. No information will be lost.

Comment: @YuHao: Ha, that's really neat, so you are exploiting the fact that member variables of tm structure are actually quite little right? like [0,..23], [0,...11] ... etc.